# SRW lock in shared memory

Tags: c++, winapi

Can [SRW Locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx) be used between processes when placed in shared memory?

Their memory footprint only seems to be a single pointer, but I am unable to find documentation on what actually happens in the background when locking.

I would like to avoid kernel mutexes if possible, but it starts to look like I am entering undefined behaviour land.

Comment: http://www.flounder.com/msdn_documentation_errors_and_omissions.htm#InitializeSRWLock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SRW Locks cannot be shared between processes. This is implied by pointed omission in the opening sentence of the documentation that says

> Slim reader/writer (SRW) locks enable the threads **of a single process** to access shared resources...

These objects take advantage of the fact that they are used within a single process. For example, the threads waiting to enter the lock are tracked in the form of a linked list. This list of waiting threads obviously has to be kept **somewhere** outside the SRWLock, seeing as the SRWLock is only the size of a single pointer, and you can't put a list of 10 threads inside a single pointer. That linked list won't accessible to other processes.

Answer (score 0):

SRW is an user object (just like critical-sections), and not kernel objects. They cannot be shared between processes. They don't have name.

SRW are implemented for performance - they are faster than critical-sections (and obviously faster than mutexes). They don't allow recursive locks (CS and mutexes allows).

Since, the are implemented for speed and performance - they are designed for same process access only. Putting a SRW handle on shared memory won't make it *available* for other process to start using it. SRW is just an opaque handle for the internal implementation. When handle is mapped by a process, it is into same process boundary - cannot be shared by other process. Since they are not kernel objects, handle inheritance is also not possible.